# Еще немного о числительных

Tags: числительные

1. По поводу слова « целые».  Почему бы не считать его СУБСТАНТИВИРОВАННЫМ ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНЫМ, то есть словом, перешедшим в класс существительных: пять целых частей → пять целых. А то эти части, которые пишутся в скобках, как-то утомляют. Похоже примерно на следующее: пять отдыхающих (людей). Тогда не нужно будет называть «целое» прилагательным, и оно не будет отличаться от обычных существительных в следующих сочетаниях: пять книг, пять целых (управление Р.п.) - с пятью книгами, с пятью целыми (согласование в Т.п.)
2. По поводу «ноль-нуль». Этот вопрос, конечно, много раз и везде обсуждался, но единого и всеми одобренного мнения как-то нет. Мне кажется естественным, когда в ударной позиции мы говорим «ноль» (нуль  здесь употребляется редко), а безударной позиции меняем на  обязательное «нулю, нулевой», чтобы избежать редукции О/А: ноль целых, но к нулю целых.

Поправка к тексту:было написано "пять целых частей", а надо "пять целых чисел".

Answer (score 2):

> Почему бы не считать его СУБСТАНТИВИРОВАННЫМ ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНЫМ,

Потому, что это противоречит семантике - да и грамматике.
Например, оно не допускает при себе прилагательных, подразумевает опущенную составляющую (часть или доля) и проч. 
Ко всему прочему, оно в рассматриваемых конструкциях используется исключительно в женском роде.

> единого и всеми одобренного мнения как-то нет.

Кто эти все, которые должны "одобрять мнение"?
Вопрос с нолем/нулем давно решен.
Современное употребление в качестве числительного тяготеет к "ноль" (хотя "нуль" иногда встречается, особенно - в косвенных падежах ); как самостоятельное существительное, т.е. *как название цифры* - к "нуль" ("нули и единицы").

Comment: 1. Из толкового словаря: ЦЕЛОЕ 1. Матем. Число без дроби.2.Нечто единое, нераздельное. 
Получается, что это слово по словарям уже является существительным, причем  среднего рода. Пять целых – это опять целых чисел, но не частей.
2. А как вы произносите форму "ноль" в безударной позиции: прибавить к н(Λ)лю, н(Λ)левой меридиан? Или нет?

Comment: Нулевой меридиан - это термин. Его трудно произнести по-другому.
да и вообще прилагательное - нулевой (если не технический текст).  
"Прибавить к нулю" - никак не произношу. Неестественное сочетание. 
Вот если "ваше отношение к абсолютному нолю" - то это зависит от конетекста. "Абсолютный ноль" - это температура, а "абсолютный нуль" - Мишка из параллельного пятого "Б".

Скорее всего - по обычным правилам, "нуль" - в косвенных падежах. Но "к нолю целых и одной десятой".

Comment: > 1. Матем. Число без дроби.  
  
Да. Но и тут весьма сомнительная субстантивированность. "Целое число", реже - "целое значение".  Только в таком значении и используется. А если "целая величина"?

>2.Нечто единое, нераздельное. Получается, 

Не получается. 

В обоих случаях - не то значение. В дробях-то - только целая (единица, часть или доля). 
"Одна целая и пять десятых (части)яблока" А не "одно целое и пять десятых яблока". Хотя, признаю, последний вариант сейчас почти уже вытеснил правильный. Но с этим еще можно мириться в разговорной речи. Но только там.

Comment: > София: "Пять целых – это опять целых чисел, но не частей."

*опять* — это опечатка?


---------------------- 
В дробях — прилагательное как определение к единице измерения. *В бак помещается 47 целых (частей = литров) и 5 десятых литра бензина*. Базовая единица (часть) измерения для данного случая — 1 литр; доли целого — количество и кратность деления — задаются дробной частью числа.

Comment: У Ожегова определение "целого" несколько другое: ЦЕЛОЕ,  ср.  Нечто  единое, нераздельное-  Стройное  целое. Единое целое. * Целое число или целое - число, состоящее из единиц (в  1 энач.) (не содержащее  дроби). (Единица у него - действительное число в математике).

То есть само понятие "целое" в значении "единое и нераздельное" применяется к числу в математике, как к частному варианту. Вообще, математика наука точная, а здесь порядка как-то нет.
А почему по поводу ноля-нуля все молчат? А то "прибавить к нолю" расстраивает, огорчает и печалит мое зрение.

Comment: И по поводу бензина в литрах. Мне кажется, сначала надо дать точное определение смешанного числа в математике, а потом непосредственно применять его на практике. Хотелось бы от частей,долей, величин или чисел перейти к более абстрактным понятиям. Кстати, в математике числа и величины, кажется, строго различают?

Comment: Насчет ноля-нуля я с Вами согласна. Я также произношу. Кстати, про бездарного и безграмотного скажу "полный ноль!", а не "полный нуль"

Comment: @Hermit

>В бак помещается 47 целых (частей = литров) и 5 десятых литра бензина.   

Оно, конечно, здесь не критично, но я никак не могу понять откуда это массовое заблуждение (дабы не сказать "помешателство") что "частей = литров". 
*47 целых (и сколько-то дробных) **частей литра**.*

Comment: Это не заблуждение, а обречённость наделять слово *часть* разными смыслами:

1) целая часть смешанного числа (47),

2) часть как единица измерения (1 литр), которая подвержена при номинации количества умножению (на 47) и делению (на 10 в данном случае),

3) часть целой единицы (1 литра), она же доля, получаемая делением единицы и в конкретных случаях наделяемая собственным именем — миллилитр; дециметр, сантиметр, миллиметр.

Answer (score 1):

По поводу употребления слов "ноль" и "нуль"

Я использую:

- слово "ноль", когда называю число 0,
- слово "нуль", когда называю цифру 0.

По моим сведениям, число 0 ("ноль") отличается от цифры 0 ("нуль") не меньше, чем:

- слово (местоимение) "я" отличается от буквы "я",
- слово (союз) "и" отличается от буквы "и",
- слово (предлог) "в" отличается от буквы "в".

Comment: 1. А почему вы сравниваете цифры с числами, ведь речь шла о величинах и числах. Именно между ними не все видят разницу. 
2. И потом: в тетради я вижу цифры, которые обозначают числа, и мне нужно их озвучить, например: к нулю целых пяти десятым прибавить ноль целых три десятых.
Как вы употребляете слова  ноль и нуль в этих случаях?

Comment: Я не употребляю набор слов "к нулю целых пяти десятым прибавить ноль целых три десятых", потому что не знаю, как следует квалифицировать этот набор слов.

Вместе с тем, я употребляю набор слов "Прибавь ноль целых пять десятых к нолю целых трём десятым.", потому что знаю, что этот набор слов следует квалифицировать как предложение в повелительном наклонении.

Я буду Вам благодарен, если Вы объясните мне, как следует квалифицировать набор слов "к нулю целых пяти десятым прибавить ноль целых три десятых".

Comment: Ну давайте предложение составим, например: Для решения задачи нам надо "к нулю целых пяти десятым прибавить ноль целых три десятых". Безличное предложение, составное глагольное сказуемое "надо прибавить", а дальше два дополнения - что и к  к чему.
По вашему ответу я вижу, что вы используете форму "к нолю". А вы редуцируете гласный О в безударной позиции?

Comment: София, большое спасибо за пояснение. Оказывается, набор слов "к нулю целых пяти десятым прибавить ноль целых три десятых" является фрагментом безличного предложения, каковой фрагмент, в свою очередь, состоит из фрагмента составного глагольного сказуемого "надо прибавить" и двух дополнений (прямого и косвенного). Боже мой, что только терпят дети в школе!

Я не редуцирую гласный "о" в безударной позиции, потому что, как правило, говорю по-русски: "Прибавь пять десятых к трём десятым.", "Умножь одну шестую на две седьмых." и т. д.

Comment: А ВЫ математик? Тогда хочу  сказать, что от математики и физики дети "терпят" гораздо больше (смайлик). Мне доводилось заниматься с детьми 8-11 классов (русским языком и всеми другими науками), и я имею  представление о современной программе  точных наук. И не однажды мне приходила мысль о том, как же прост курс школьной грамматики по сравнению с интегральным исчислением, всякими там рядами или циклами Карно. Все интеллектуальные способности детей уходят на математику, на русский язык мало что остается. В то же время языком мы пользуемся ежедневно, а математика нужна для простого счета.